# Copy Rotation Problem

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

Gear_A and Object_B, I want the rotation speed of B to be 1/6 of A, A is the controller(pic1).
I use bone to achieve this.It looks OK, when the angle of A is 180, the angle of B will be 30(pic2),but when A is 181, B is not a little bigger than 30, it jump to -30/330(pic3).

I have tried some other shape and different influence, It seems that when the rotation is 180,blender will replace it with -180, and than add the angle again.It is OK for single rotation,but what I want is the animation, when A rotate 720, B should rotate 120, but in this case, it turns out 0.

Is there some settings to achieve that?
keyframe and driver are not recommended cause there are CDEF and many other objects.
Thanks a lot.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: pls click on the checkmark left to an answer, if it helped you. Thanks. https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the way copy rot modifier works. Drivers are absolutely the solution: you can create a Master bone, hover over its Y euler rot channel, right click "Copy as new driver". Then Hover over Y rot value of slave bones, right click "Paste driver".
Then edit drivers choosign "scripted expression" and adding the needed operation (i.e. rotation_euler/6).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sadlly it don't works，when A goes to 180, B shows -30, still the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure? It's working to me. 180/6=30. Only a sign problem?

Comment: Done！The key is that I don't know that the variable has different type, by default it is "Transform Channel" and what you use is "Single Property", I got why.Thank you very very much!